# "peeking" at available space for writing data to a pipe in linux?

Tags: linux

I'm working on an implementation of multi-reader pipes in Linux that will utilize tee() and an intermediate process to move data from a "writer" pipe into one or more "reader" pipes.  I've figured out all the details except one.  I need to make sure I'm not writing data to any one pipe more than the others, so it doesn't "get ahead".

I can do this by looking at the "reader" pipes and taking the minimum amount of available space and writing that.  But, I'm not aware of a mechanism to peek on the amount of buffer space available in a pipe before blocking.  Is there a way to do such in Linux?

Comment: Does `ioctl()` with `FIONREAD` flag works on with your pipes on your version of Linux? And perhaps you actually mean `tee()` instead of `splice()`?

Comment: I don't know if it does or not, I'll check.  I think FIONREAD returns how many bytes are available to be read right?  Not how many you _can_ write?  I'd like something POSIX if possible.  And yes I meant tee(), not splice(), I'll change it.